# Prove that $\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\frac{1^2}{2!}+\frac{(1.2)^2}{4!}+...}{\frac{(-1)^2}{1!}+\frac{(-1.1)^2}{3!}+\frac{(-1.1.3)^2}{5!}+...}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I used a Taylor series expansion of the product of trigonometric functions

Assume
$$\arccos(x)\arcsin(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots$$
The expansion is:

$$\arccos(x)\arcsin(x)=0+\frac{\pi}{2}x-x^2+\frac{\pi}{(2\cdot3!)}x^3-\frac{8}{4!}x^4-\frac{9\pi}{2\cdot5!}x^5-\frac{128}{6!}x^6+\dotsb$$

Substitute $x=1$, LHS becomes $0$:

$$0=\frac{\pi}{2}-1+\frac{\pi}{(2\cdot3!)}-\frac{8}{4!}-\frac{9\pi}{(2\cdot5)!}-\frac{128}{6!}+\dotsb$$

So,
$$2\left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{(1\cdot2)^2}{4!}+\frac{(1\cdot2\cdot4)^2}{6!}+\dotsb\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{(1\cdot-1)^2}{1!}+\frac{(1\cdot1)^2}{3!}+\frac{(1\cdot3)^2}{5!}+\frac{(1\cdot3\cdot5)^2}{7!}+\dotsb\right)$$

Rearranging gives
$$\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\dfrac{(1)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(1\cdot2)^2}{4!}+\dfrac{(1\cdot2\cdot4)^2}{6!}+\dfrac{(1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot6)^2}{8!}+\dotsb}{\dfrac{(-1)^2}{1!}+\dfrac{(-1\cdot1)^2}{3!}+\dfrac{(-1\cdot1\cdot3)^2}{5!}+\dfrac{(-1\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5)^2}{7!}+\dotsb}$$

I appreciate any alternate derivations for this result

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include your work?

Comment: yes yes will do

Comment: Please improve the typesetting. In particular, use \cdot for multiplication.

Comment: When you substitute a value $x=1$, does the resulting series converge?

Comment: `\cdot` for $\cdot$, `\arccos` for $\arccos$, `\arcsin` for $\arcsin$, `\ldots` for $\ldots$, `a_0`, for $a_0$, etc.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, there's a germ of something sensible here. The ratio of the $n$th numerator partial sum to the $n$th denominator partial sum is asymptotic to $\frac{\pi}{4n}$; if the numerator has one extra term, the ratio is asymptotic to $\frac{n\pi}{4}$; the geometric mean of these is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. (To prove these results, use $\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$.)

Comment: Interesting so this summation is not entirely completely stupid huh. Thank you. Also I found this stupid summation independently but I would like to know where else this representation of π has been discovered before.

Comment: Your expansion of $\arccos x\arcsin x$ seems wrong. E.g. the first term sould be $\frac\pi2x,$ not $-2x.$

Comment: Thank you, I made several mistakes while deriving the result. Thank you for pointing them out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
\frac{\dfrac{(1)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(1\cdot2)^2}{4!}+\dfrac{(1\cdot2\cdot4)^2}{6!}+\dfrac{(1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot6)^2}{8!}+\dotsb}{\dfrac{(-1)^2}{1!}+\dfrac{(-1\cdot1)^2}{3!}+\dfrac{(-1\cdot1\cdot3)^2}{5!}+\dfrac{(-1\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5)^2}{7!}+\dotsb} .
$$
The numerator is $N(1)$, where
$$
N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{((2n)!!)^2}{(2n+2)!} x^{2n+2} 
= \frac{(\arcsin x)^2}{2}
$$
The denominator is $D(1)$, where
$$
D(x) = x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}
=\arcsin x .
$$
So
$$
N(1) = \frac{(\arcsin 1)^2}{2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}
\\
D(1) = \arcsin 1 = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and our result is
$$
\frac{N(1)}{D(1)} = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$

Comment: Very nice thank you. Are the N and D functions also Taylor expansions of arcsin?